# Building a list of entries from a single category with exp:query

Tags: query, sql

I'm trying to speed my site up with a few direct queries.

Like:

> {exp:query sql="SELECT field_id_16 FROM exp_channel_data WHERE channel_id='4' "}
> {field_id_16}
>
> {/exp:query}

What query will I need to restrict these entries to a certain category? I'll probably need to join exp_category_posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head I'm pretty sure this should work for you :

```
SELECT field_id_16 FROM exp_channel_data cd
LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts cp
ON cd.entry_id = cp.entry_id
WHERE cp.cat_id = 1
```

Change the cp.cat_id = 1 number to whichever category ID you need and I'm fairly certain you should be good to go.

Comment: No problem. Glad that helped. :-)